# how to create a table having spaces between the words?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to create a table using code.

Here is my code.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { con.Close(); }
    con.Open();
    string s = "CREATE TABLE "+"" + rchtxtFieldCode.Text + " "+ " (" + rchFieldTitle.Text + " " + combDataType.Text + "" + ")";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("created");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

It is creating the table if the table name has single word.. It is showing exception if there is space between the words(eg: Sales Info)

Comment: Please add the tag for the database that this is for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add Box braces:

```
string s = "CREATE TABLE ["+"" + rchtxtFieldCode.Text + "] "+ " (" + rchFieldTitle.Text + " " + combDataType.Text + "" + ")";
                       //^_______________________________^
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is for SQL Server you use square brackets:

```
string s = "CREATE TABLE ["+"" + rchtxtFieldCode.Text + "] "+ " ([" + rchFieldTitle.Text + "] " + combDataType.Text + "" + ")";
```

In fact you should always use square brackets to stop these kind of errors happening.

Also ensure you are sanitising your strings otherwise you might have SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use spaces in table or field names.In this, Try to change query with Square brackets i.e.

For example ,

```
sqlString = "CREATE TABLE [All Students]"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code, i think it will give you the desire output.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { con.Close(); }
        con.Open();
        string s = "CREATE TABLE '"+rchtxtFieldCode.Text + "'(" +"'"+rchFieldTitle.Text +"'" + combDataType.Text + "" + ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("created");
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```